# Request method PUT not supported with Spring webClient call on dockerized app

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I've made a simple SpringBoot project with 3 microservices, built by docker-compose.yml.

When I try to communicate between microservices with a Spring WebClient call, I received

> 405 Request method 'PUT' not supported  http://transactions-ms:8080/sendAccountTransaction

but if I made a Postman call the transactions microservice is reachable and other webclient calls (with another WebClient contained in other microservices) work fine.

**WebClient (URI: http://transactions-ms:8080/sendAccountTransaction)**

```
public ResponseEntity<SavedTransactionRTO> sendAccountTransaction(SendTransactionRequest request) {
        SavedTransactionRTO response = webClient.put()
                .uri(ClientUrl.TRANSACTIONS_URL+ClientEndp.SEND_ACC_TRANSACTION)
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(SavedTransactionRTO.class)
                .block();
        return new  ResponseEntity<SavedTransactionRTO>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Controller method:**

```
@PutMapping(value = "/sendAccountTransaction", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<SavedTransactionRTO> sendAccountTransaction(@RequestBody SendTransactionRequest request){ 
        SavedTransactionRTO response = transactionService.sendAccountTransaction(request);      
        return new ResponseEntity<SavedTransactionRTO>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
   transactions-ms:
      image: transactions-ms
      hostname: transactions-ms
      container_name: transactions-ms
      build:
         context: ./transactions-ms
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
         - "8080:8080"
              
   accounts-ms:
      image: accounts-ms
      hostname: accounts-ms
      container_name: accounts-ms
      depends_on:
         transactions-ms:
            condition: service_started
      build:
         context: ./accounts-ms
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
         - "8081:8081"
      
   customers-ms:
      image: customers-ms
      hostname: customers-ms  
      container_name : customers-ms
      depends_on:
          accounts-ms:
            condition: service_started
      build:
         context: ./customers-ms
         dockerfile: Dockerfile   
      ports:
         - "8082:8082"
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080 
ADD target/transactions-ms.jar transactions-ms.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/transactions-ms.jar"]
```

I have made all possible attempts, anyone has a solution?

Comment: Any other mapping mentioned in your controller class?

Comment: @SounakSaha in my RestController there are some GetMapping and DeleteMapping methods. I've tried to change my PutMapping on a PostMapping method but i receive the same error type.